# Ecology 2d Struct Array C++

Tags: c++

Code prints a 2d array from Time 0-100 alright but now what im trying to do is put functions like birthrate,dying rate, and reproduction for the plants,antelopes, and tigers as each day passes time[o]. Are those functions going to be another VOID or in INT MAIN. As well if i try to for example... Rp(reproduction of plants)= t[i].Plants + 30; it will not compile and run because i can not add 30 to t[i].Plants im trying to add 30 additional plants at the end of Day 1 so in Day 2 there is a new number for Plants to start off with as it repeats till day 100.

Trying to print something like this in regards to Plants Antelopes and Tigers and Time with fuctions involved like birthrate,dying rate, and reproduction. Time will be 0-100 but other values will change.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru35X.jpg)

Thank you for your help i really appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct population {
    string Plants;
    string Antelopes;
    string Tigers;
    double time[100];
};
 void input (population[]); 
 void print (population[]);
 void initialize (population[]); 
 void birthrate (population []);
 int main ()
 {
      int Time[100];
     int Plants[100];
     int Antelopes[100];
     int Tigers[100];
     cout << " Time - Plants - Antelopes - Tigers \n";
     cout << " --------------------------------------- \n";
for ( int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Time[0]= i ;
    Plants[0] =i;
    Antelopes[0] =i;
    Tigers[0] =i;
    cout << " " << Time[0] << " ----  " << " " << Plants[0] <<  " ----  " <<  " " << Antelopes[0] <<  " ----  " << " " << Tigers[0] << endl;
}
 // int plants;
 // cout << " Enter value for plants " << endl;
 // cin >> plants;

 }

void initialize (population t[])
 {
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++)
{
    t[i].Plants = "";
    t[i].Antelopes = "";
    t[i].Tigers = "";
    for (int j=0; j < 100; j++)
        t[i].time[j] = 0;
     }
 }

     void input (population t[])
 {
        for (int i=0; i < 1; i++)
         {
        cout << " Enter initial population for Plants ";
        cin >> t[i].Plants;
        cout << " \n Enter initial population for Antelopes ";
        cin >> t[i].Antelopes;
        cout << " \n Enter initial population for Tigers ";
        cin >> t[i].Tigers;
        for (int j=0; j < 100; j++)
             {
            cout << "\n Enter time ";
            cin >> t[i].time[j];
             }          
         }
}
 void print (population t[])
 {
     for (int i=0; i < 1; i++)
    {
    cout << " Plants Pop: " << t[i].Plants << endl;
    cout << " Antelopes Pop: " << t[i].Antelopes << endl;
    cout << " Tigers Pop: " << t[i].Tigers << endl;
for (int j=0; j < 100; j++)
    cout << " " << t[i].time[j];
    cout << endl;
    }
 }  
void birthrate (population t[])
{
for (int i=0; i <= 100; i++)
{   
string Rp;
Rp = (t[i].Plants);
cout << " " << Rp << endl;
for (int j=0; j < 100; j++)
    cout << t[i].Plants[j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `for ( int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)` -> `for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++)`

Comment: It looks like you need to use classes. Make a class Plants, class Antelopes, class Tigers, and have population be a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of major issues preventing giving good advice on how to proceed.

You're making a class to store all the pop values, but that is using a string. Store numeric data instead.

Then, you're not even using that class inside your main loop at all, you're making some entirely unconnected new variables and using them. Basically chop out the excess variables. This is a basic outline:

```
struct sample
{
    float pop;
    float deaths;
    float births;
};

struct population
{
    sample Plants;
    sample Antelopes;
    sample Tigers;
}
```

Now, each "population" object will hold a snapshot of the entire population at one point in time. *If* you want to store 100 snapshots (which is not really necessary), you could then make an array of 100 population objects:

```
population pop[100];
```

But it's almost certainly better to just have one population object that stores the current time slice:

```
population ecoSystem;
```

And just print the values as they're updated. There's absolutely no need to store 100 time points worth of data, unless that's a requirement to save them to a file. You'd access the values like this:

```
void input(population& p) // & = pass in a live reference to the population object
{
    cout << " Enter initial population for Plants ";
    cin >> p.Plants.pop;
    cout << " \n Enter initial population for Antelopes ";
    cin >> p.Antelopes.pop;
    cout << " \n Enter initial population for Tigers ";
    cin >> p.Tigers.pop;
}
```

And there's no basic reason to input 100 data points worth of info at once, you just cycle through the update 100 times and have a separate "int t" time variable for which time slice you're up to. At most, you want the current population variable, an another population variable for the next time slice, which you then copy back into the current one after calculating the update.

Comment: This clarified so much thank you and yeah reason for 100 is cause the project calls for 100 days worth of the ecosystem but thank you again ill definitely use this.